# In Node.js, can I assign value to variable through a callback function of readFile()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

code1

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile(process.argv[2],"utf8",function(err,data){
    if(err)throw err;
    console.log(data.split(/\n/).length-1);
});
```

code2

```
var fs = require("fs");
var str;
fs.readFile(process.argv[2],'utf8',function(err,data){
    if(err)throw err;
    str=data;
});
var arr = str.split(/\n/);
console.log(arr.length-1);
```

Hi everyone, I'm learning for node.js now, and above code is to read a file then count the number of its newlines asynchronously. 
For code1, it can work correctly, but for code2, str will get "undefined" value. I have no idea why it happened, does that mean I can not assign variable in the callback function? Or do I miss anything else? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var arr = str.split(/\n/);` is executed before the file is read. At this point str is still `undefined`. The callback is intended to be the code that executes after the async process is completed. This allows node to be responsive while (generally) only having a single thread.

Node also has a `readFileSync` method, but this generally defeats the purpose of using Node since your entire program will block while the file is read.